# Change default expandable table row in jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, expandable

I need example of expandable table row, I found this is the best choice so far:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-For-Expandable-Bootstrap-Table-Rows.html

demo: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Expandable-Bootstrap-Table-Rows/

The table will expand when I click the header.
My question is: how to make the table expanded by default?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write jQuery for this. Below code should help to solve your query.

```
$("table tbody tr:first-child").next("tr").toggle();
$("table tbody tr:first-child").find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
```

Answer (score 0):

add this below jquery will keep table expanded by default once document is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tbody>tr").css("display", "table-row");
});
```

Comment: You are always welcome :) If it is useful give a vote :)

Comment: sure I voted it immediately yesterday, but there is message: "Thanks for the feedback, Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score".